# lottie-web setting container value using useRef TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lottie

`container` is complaining because `HTMLDivElement | null` is not assignable to Element type

```
export const Loader: React.FC = () => {
  const element = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);  
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    lottie.loadAnimation({
      animationData,
      container: element.current,
      loop: true
    });
  });

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div ref={element}></div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Try `null as any`

Comment: @oemera the container is typed to only accepts Element type, 
```container: Element```

Comment: Can you show the exact error message?

Comment: @oemera
`Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.`
on the lottie package: index.d.ts(53, 5): The expected type comes from property 'container' which is declared here on type 'AnimationConfigWithPath | AnimationConfigWithData'

Comment: @oemera as far as I know the useRef should already have value on it upon calling inside the useLayoutEffect

Comment: I don't think thats true. Thats true for `useEffect`. But you still initialized your `useRef` with `null`, so the type is `HTMLDivElement | null` even if it can't ever be null in the `useEffect`. You have to check manually, if it is null. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make sure `element.current` has a value before you call `loadAnimation`. Try this:

```
export const Loader: React.FC = () => {
  const element = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(element.current) // add this
       lottie.loadAnimation({
         animationData,
         container: element.current,
         loop: true
       });
  }, [element]); // add this, it triggers this effect everytime element changes

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div ref={element}></div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

**OR**

```
container: element.current as HTMLDivElement,
```

**OR**

```
container: element.current!,
```

The first option is the cleanest, since it's less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for this! this is the correct answer. Tho still need to put `null` inside the `useRef`

also I omitted the dependency because warning says:
React Hook useLayoutEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'element.current'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 'element.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component

Comment: `element` instead of `element.current` on the hook dependency works